# jquery - get parent of parent?

Tags: jquery, image, parent, scale

I'm using the jquery.cjobjectScaler plugin ([link text](http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/a-jquery-plug-in-to-scale-objects-to-fit-or-fill-within-another-object) ) and due to circumstances beyond my control, the img is hyperlinked within the div...  I don't have any way to "strip out" that  tag, nor can I reorder it at all...

So, the original function is this:

```
$("#productGrid li img").cjObjectScaler({
    destObj: $("#productGrid li img").parent("li"), // must be a jQuery object (required)
    method: "fit", // can either be fit or fill (default fill)
    fade: 800 // if a positive integer, will hide and fadeIn object n duration (default 0)
});

/* CSS for above */

ul#productGrid li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-right:
    10px; margin-bottom:
    10px; overflow: hidden;
}
```

And this is the version I'm trying to use...

```
$(".ffts a img").cjObjectScaler({
     destObj: $(".ffts a img").parent("a"),
     method: "fill",
});

/* css for above */
.ffts a {
    width: 550px; 
    height: 300px;
}

/* here's the markup */
<div class="ffts">
     <a href="/img" style="position: relative;">
     <img src="/source/image.jpg" />
     </a>        
</div>
```

And, it does resize it, but not to the dimensions set for ffts a...  I've verified that that style isn't being overridden, so not sure where to go from here... ?

Comment: What does it resize to then? `ffts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear, but if you just wanted to "get parent of parent", use the `prev()` or `parents()` selectors.

Comment: meh... I figured it out about 2 seconds after I posted :)

Answer (score 0):

simply try

```
destObj: $(".ffts>a")
```